# How to configure vim spellcheck to use two languages

Tags: vim, spell-check

In my blog I write blog posts in German language. But as my blog is mostly about technology, there are many English words appearing as well.

I recently enabled German spell-checking in `vim` with

```
set spell spelllang=de_de
```

Of course, it is highlighting all the English words now. Is there any way to use `en_US` and `de_DE` at the same time?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`:help 'spelllang'` tells that the option can contain *"A comma separated list of word list names."* So, the following should work already:

```
:set spelllang=en_us,de_de
```